# setting up google oauth for multiple web applications

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-people-api

I'm currently developing a feature that includes accessing Google's resource (people API). currently my company has multiple applications deployed for our clients. each applications has their own unique domain. as far as I know, I need to create separate Oauth client credentials for each of the applications. is there a way to automate the process of creating the credentials in GCP? I'm pretty new with this Oauth stuff.

note: I'm developing the feature using python.